# Add multiple recipient email addresses Joomla Page Builder

Tags: php

I am using Joomla and SP Page Builder. I have back-end side and front-end side. I would like to add multiple recipients for sent emails from my contact form. I have found related codes for sending emails. What should be edited to add multiple email addresses on my back-end? I have tried to play with

```
$recipients = array(
  "address@domain.com",
);
$email_to = implode(',', $recipients);
```

with no success

Here is my front-end code:

```
$recipient_email = (isset($this->addon->settings->recipient_email) && $this->addon->settings->recipient_email) ? $this->addon->settings->recipient_email : '';
```

Here is what I have in back-end:

```
    'recipient_email'=>array(
        'type'=>'text',
        'title'=>JText::_('COM_SPPAGEBUILDER_ADDON_AJAX_CONTACT_RECIPIENT_EMAIL'),
        'desc'=>JText::_('COM_SPPAGEBUILDER_ADDON_AJAX_CONTACT_RECIPIENT_EMAIL_DESC'),
        'std'=>'email@yourdomain.com'
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it this way...

1) Create an override folder (if not existing) in your template folder for the Contact Form add-on. Copy the content from

```
<joomla_root_path>/components/com_sppagebuilder/addons/ajax_contact
```

to

```
<joomla_root_path>/templates/sppagebuilder/addons/ajax_contact
```

2) In the `admin.php` file add the following code after `'recipient_email'` array

```
'recipient_email_2' => array(
  'type' => 'text',
  'title' => JText::_( 'COM_SPPAGEBUILDER_ADDON_AJAX_CONTACT_RECIPIENT_EMAIL' ) . ' 2',
  'desc' => 'This is another recipient email address. Optional.',
  'std' => 'email@yourdomain.com'
),
```

3) In the `site.php` file add the following code.

In the `public function render()` Under the `//Addon options` add the following code:

```
$recipient_email_2 = ( isset( $this->addon->settings->recipient_email_2 ) && $this->addon->settings->recipient_email_2 ) ? $this->addon->settings->recipient_email_2 : '';
```

Then search for this line:

```
$output .= '<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="' . base64_encode( $recipient_email ) . '">';
```

And add the following below:

```
$output .= '<input type="hidden" name="recipient-2" value="' . base64_encode( $recipient_email_2 ) . '">';
```

In the `public function getAjax()` under the `//inputs` search for this code:

```
  if ( $input[ 'name' ] == 'recipient' ) {
    $recipient = base64_decode( $input[ 'value' ] );
  }
```

Proceed to add this below:

```
  if ( $input[ 'name' ] == 'recipient-2' ) {
    $recipient_2 = base64_decode( $input[ 'value' ] );
  }
```

Then search for this line:

```
$mail->setSender( $sender );
```

And add this code below:

```
if ( isset( $recipient_2 ) && !empty( $recipient_2 ) ) {
  $recipientArray = array( $recipient, $recipient_2 );
  $mail->addRecipient( $recipientArray );
} else {
  $mail->addRecipient( $recipient );
}
```

That's it! You should see a new field in the administrator and it should works as expected with one recipient or two.

[image]

Hope it helps! Regards.

Comment: Some facts about checking if a variable is set and/or empty... `$recipient_email_2 = ( isset( $this->addon->settings->recipient_email_2 ) && $this->addon->settings->recipient_email_2 ) ? $this->addon->settings->recipient_email_2 : '';` is written more succinctly as `$recipient_email_2 = empty($this->addon->settings->recipient_email_2) ? $this->addon->settings->recipient_email_2 : '';` or even better with the null coalescing operator `$recipient_email_2 = $this->addon->settings->recipient_email_2 ?? '';`.

Comment: Also, `if ( isset( $recipient_2 ) && !empty( $recipient_2 ) ) {` is performing a redundant check.  `empty()` does 2 things: it checks if the variable is not set AND is contains a false-y/empty/zero-ish/null value.  For this reason `isset()` can be safely omitted.  `if (!empty($recipient_2 )) {`  [Read more on this topic...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/2943403)

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for your comments, they help us improve our coding practices!